# Can we include testng @priority and @dataprovider in same bracket?

Tags: testng-dataprovider

I have a method having annotation `@Test` and have set its `priority=1`, data-Provider annotation after priority, but when i run my class it skips the method having `priority=1` and execute the the other method having `priority=2`.

I think i am not doing it correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

1. It does not matter what order you place annotation properties in. i.e. The following are the same:

   - `@Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "...")`
   - `@Test(dataProvider = "...", priority = 1)`
2. Setting a `priority` and a `dataProvider` should work as expected. Here is an example test to demonstrate such:

   ```java
   import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

   public class ExampleTest {
       private int runFirstInvocationCount = 0;

       @Test(priority = 2)
       public void runSecond() {
           assertEquals(runFirstInvocationCount, data().length);
       }

       @DataProvider
       public static Object[][] data() {
           return new Object[][]{
                   {/* your data values here */},
                   {/* your data values here */},
                   {/* your data values here */}
           };
       }

       @Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "data")
       public void runFirst(/* your data parameters here */) {
           runFirstInvocationCount++;
       }
   }
   ```